# How to get Oracle FAN down or UP event in C# ODP.Net code?

Tags: odp.net, oracle-rac

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RACAD/GUID-1A7346B1-AFE3-4B17-AD7E-E35FE628CDF9.htm#RACAD7136

Oracle ODP.Net provides way to capture FAN events when RAC goes up or down. Is there a way to capture this in C# code. I am not able to see any example of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HA Events classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/odp-dot-net-ha-event-classes.html